# Register user WPMU with verification - WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wpmu

I am trying to register a user with WPMU  with verifications.

I am using `wpmu_create_user($email, $pass, $email)`, but this register a user directly without an email confirmation.

Is there another method or I need to create that logic from scratch ?

Answer (score 0):

I am using `wpmu_signup_user( $username, $email, apply_filters( 'add_signup_meta', array() ) );`